# Open Folder specifed in edittext android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-file, android-external-storage

Am working on showing images from gallery BELOW IS THE CODE. 
HERE i want to open images in a specific folder which name will be given in a edit text.
Please help me in doing it as currently its opening all the images which is irrelevant to the application and hard for me to identify the images.

```
protected void LoadGalleryImages() {
        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);
        int image_column_index = 0;

        if (imagecursor != null) {
            image_column_index = imagecursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            count = imagecursor.getCount();
        }

        imgSelected = new String[count];

        arrPath = new String[count];
        thumbnailsselection = new boolean[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (imagecursor != null) {
                imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
                // int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

                arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pooja,

Here is the code to open your specified folder to browse your files:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("folder path");

//Change content type as you want if you dont know then just mention "*/*"
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Do you mean, where to write this code? If yes, then just replace definition of "LoadGalleryImages()" with my code. It should work.

Comment: I got the solution in the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200309/android-display-images-from-specific-folder-in-gallery-view?rq=1