# How to display images from specific folder in gallery application?

Tags: java, android, path, gallery, android-internal-storage

I'm trying to make a gallery application which **only shows images from screenshot folder in my internal storage.**

I found a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200309/android-display-images-from-specific-folder-in-gallery-view)  but I'm having difficulties on how to specify the path to my desired folder.

This is the snippet:

```
cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        columns, 
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                        new String[] {"%/yourfoldername/%"},  
                        null);
```

Can someone explain me what should I put in this `" like ? "` and how can I specify my folder name in this `new String[] {"%/yourfoldername/%"},`

This is my code.

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED };

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                    new String[] {"%/sdcard/DCIM/Screenshots"},
                    null);
```

Any corrections will be highly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        assert cursor != null;
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but where should I put this snippet? Sorry I'm new to java. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: it is a function that need to a context activity and the uri from you image, the function return a string with the root of your image, you can see it using Picasso